# How do I access an itertools.combinations object without converting it to a list

Tags: python-3.x, python-itertools

I am trying to create a Python program to return every possible combination of characters you can type on a keyboard. I have got a numpy array, and I am using itertools.combinations to achieve this. However, itertools returns a huge list that I cannot directly access. How could I access only one value from the memory address without converting the object to a list?

This is my current code.

```
import keyboard
import ctypes
import numpy as np
from itertools import combinations

characters = np.array(["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9","0 ", "!", "@", "#", "$", "%", "^", "&", "*", "(", ")", "-", "_", "=", "+", "\\", "|", ";", ":", "'", "<", ".", ">", "/", "?", "`", "~", "[", "]", "{", "}", ",", " "])
combos = np.array([])
val = np.array([])
address = 0
for i in range(20):
    np.append(val, combinations(characters, 21 - i))
    print(val, len(combinations(characters, 21 - i)))
lst = 0
for j in range(len(val)):
    combos.append(tuple(ctypes.cast(id(ctypes.cast(id(val[j]), ctypes.py_object).value), ctypes.py_object).value))
print(combos)
```

Comment: Consider using generators with the `yield` keyword.